# Thread Synchronization in android

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I have Two services

1. Service A
2. Service B
3. Service c

**Service A Code:**

```
public class ServiceA extends Service  {


    @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    testfunction1();
            Thread1();

}

public synchronized void testfunction1(){
    Log.d("Thread","Hi I Am Test 1");
}

public void Thread1(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);

                }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                testfunction1();

            }
          }                        
        }).start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

**Service B Code**

```
public class ServiceB extends Service  {


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    testfunction2();
            Thread2();
}

public synchronized void testfunction2(){
    Log.d("Thread","Hi I Am Test 2");
}

public void Thread2(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);

                }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                testfunction2();

            }
          }                        
        }).start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Edit: Service 3 Added

```
**Service C Code**

    public class ServiceC extends Service  {


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Intent ServiceA = new Intent("ServiceA Package Name");
        this.startService(ServiceA);
        Intent ServiceB = new Intent("ServiceB Package Name");
        this.startService(ServiceB);
        ServiceA admin = new ServiceA();
        admin.Thread1();
        ServiceB security = new ServiceB();
        security.Thread2();
    }
}
```

Problem is when i run that two service

it will keep on logging

Thread  Hi I Am Test 1

Thread  Hi I Am Test 1

Thread  Hi I Am Test 1

Thread  Hi I Am Test 1

Thread  Hi I Am Test 1

Thread  Hi I Am Test 1

Why I am not getting the Service 2 logs?

Comment: Do you call Thread1 and Thread2 anywhere in your code? How do you create the services? startService? bindService?

Comment: I think when the service is started it will run the code in continuation in background, and also you have Sync the testFunction1(). So it will not allowed the other functions to run.

Comment: @smichak  i called that Thread1 in ServiceA OnCreate() and i called Thread2 in ServiceB OnCreate()

Comment: Your onCreate methods only call testFunction1 and testFunction2 which print the line... I don't see how the threads get created at all. Did I miss something here?

Comment: @samintechvalens i need to create Another service c to call Service A and Service B ?

Comment: if you called the method `Thread1` of class `ServiceA`  in `OnCreate()` method then please update your code.

Comment: @smichak is right on. Bucks, look over your onCreate methods very carefully. You should have a call to Thread1(); and Thread2(); there, respectively.

Comment: Sorry guyz i missed two lines.. i Edit the code

Comment: So, assuming you're still getting the same result, can you please post the code which starts / binds the two services?

Comment: @smichak Added Another service to call that threads

Comment: You don't need another service to start those two services. You should start the services by calling startService(new Intent(this, ServiceA.class)) from your application's activity (or replace this with some other context). I think that what you wrote in Service3's onCreate doesn't actually start the service...

Comment: @smichak is it any other possibility to call the function again and again without using Thread